# Elasticsearch 'next' search terms (like Pinterest)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, pinterest

My goal is to create list of related search terms, exactly like [Pinterest](https://pinterest.com) have. For example, when I search for **"overflow"** Pinterest generates a list of related terms:

[image]
After selecting **"quotes"** it gives me another related terms:
[image]

How can I achieve this type of functionality with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution suits you, but Elasticsearch has something like [Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-suggesters.html#search-suggesters). I'm not familiar with this functionality in practice, but I see that there are several config options for this (as in entire Elasticsearch) - maybe something will work for you.

Additionally I found short introductory video for this topic here:

https://www.elastic.co/videos/using-the-completion-suggester

Please keep in mind that the video is from 2012 so the API is slightly different in current versions.

Comment: thanks, but after reading about Suggesters I don't think I can achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The [Significant Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html) should be able to get you what you want. You should be able to get the terms on either other related queries or documents depending on what data you store.

Comment: do you have/know any examples?